# Checking if no compare_price exists in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to check if there's no compare price, and I cannot get any of the following to work in Shopify:

```
{% if price > compare_at_price %}

{% if compare_at_price == 0 %}

{% if compare_at_price == "" %}
```

I want to output some HTML when the compare_price doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the object here to get its attributes:

```
{% if product.price > product.compare_at_price %}
    Do something 
{% endif %}
```

To check if there is one:

```
{% if product.compare_at_price %} 
    Do sthg
{% endif %}
```

To check if there isn't one:

```
{% unless product.compare_at_price %} 
    Do sthg
{% endunless %}
```

Documentation:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/product